# MongoDB on Google Colab : System has not been booted with systemd

Tags: mongodb, google-colaboratory

After successfully installing both MySQL and Spark on Google Colab I have become more ambitious and am trying to install, MongoDB on Google Colab ( instead of a physical Ubuntu 18.04.5 machine) and am getting stuck with

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

Since in Colab, I am the root user, I do not need to prefix my commands with sudo. During the process ... my steps are as follows

```
!apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 68818C72E52529D4

!echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list

!apt-get update

!apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

this is where it fails with

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

I would be grateful if someone can give me a work around this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
!apt install mongodb
!service mongodb start

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client.list_database_names() # ['admin', 'local']
```

Comment: Thanks! It had to be as simple as that! But I wonder why the documentation for the Ubuntu is so complicated and convoluted! .. Once again, thank you.

Comment: I tried a lot of methods, and probably failed twice. When, eventually, I found a way, I made it as simple as possible and save it as a gist. https://gist.github.com/korakot/64f4e589eff252cf0486388da26c17fd